# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 4 at JT1.main(JT1.java:11)

Tags: java, arrays, args

```
public static void main(String args[]){     
    String CopyArgs[] = new String[5];
    for(int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
       CopyArgs[i] = args[i];
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < 6;i++)
    System.out.println(CopyArgs[i]);
```

How can I solve this error?
I have already tried changing `<=` to `<` but it did not resolve the `Exception`. It appears whether I put enter `3`, `4` or `5` for `args`

> ```
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 4
> at JT1.main(JT1.java:11)
> ```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to get `CopyArgs[5]` and you don't have that index.

Try to change your second `for` loop to:

```
for (int i = 0; i < CopyArgs.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(CopyArgs[i]); 
}
```

Another simply way to print an array is:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(CopyArgs));
```

Comment: Thank you, that was the solution :)

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
for(int i = 0; i < CopyArgs.length;i++)
System.out.println(CopyArgs[i]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `System.arraycopy()` to copy an Array.

Define the copy with the same length than the original:

```
String[] copyArgs[] = new String[args.length];

System.arraycopy( args, 0, copyArgs, 0, args.length );
```

use the length of the Array not a fix value:

```
for(int i = 0; i < copyArgs.length;i++)
System.out.println(copyArgs[i]);
```

BTW: Take care of Java naming conventions. variable name should start with lower case character

Comment: `Arrays.copyOf(args, args.length)` is an easier method to call.